# What could be turning off this visual effect?

Tags: windows-7

I'm running 64 bit Windows 7 on my work PC. Whenever I log on to the PC, the *Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing* visual effect is turned off.

So I turn it on in *Performance Options*.

However, when I next log on it's turned off again.

What could be causing this setting to get turned off every time I log on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible this setting is disabled by Group/User Policies by your Administrators (or at least permanently saving them). It might be that start up scripts are run at your workplace setting default setting, the Performance Options might be one of them, you could ask your System Administrator.